# Nicest surface with a continuous map of $O(2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, manifolds

This question is kind of subjective,

I'm looking for the "nicest"  3-d surface for which there exists a smooth and continuous map of $O(2)$ to the points on the surface.

To make life easier, I can observe that $O(2)$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be mimicked by a a subgroup of $SO(3)$ and so I also wanted to consider surfaces whose points I can smoothly map to $SO(3)$ but after a fair bit of reading on wikipedia i'm embarrassed to say that its not obvious what one such surface would be (I wanted to believe the sphere but a mention to quaternions made the 4-sphere more likely and that no longer qualifies as a solution).

Comment: The "unit quaternions" are just $S^3$ (as a subset of the quaternions, topologically $\mathbb{R}^4$). If by "3-d" surface you mean a 3-dimensional manifold, then $SO(3)\cong\mathbb{RP}^3$ works, no?

Comment: I mean 2 dimesional surface floating in ambient 3d space

Comment: ah, ok, carry on then. :)

Comment: You want a smooth surjective map from $O(2)$ to a surface in $\mathbb R^3$? There is none, for $O(2)$ is a curve. (And if you do not require the map to be surjective, you can pick any surface whatsoever)

Comment: @SteveD what sort of surface is $\mathbb{RP}^3$? What is its minimum ambient dimension to avoid self intersections?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: It's a 3-dimensional manifold, not a surface. It embeds in $\mathbb{R}^5$, and that is the smallest ambient dimension.

Comment: $O(2)$ is homeomorphic to a pair of circles: one circle for $SO(2)$, parametrized on the rotation angle (as the transformations in $SO(2)$ are rotations abot the origin); the other one for the transforms with determinant -1, that are rotations composed with axis reflections.